# NPM: Missing script "start" but it is actually defined

Tags: node.js, json, npm, npm-scripts, electron-forge

I am trying to make a game in HTML CSS and JS using electron forge but when i try to run `npm start` in root directory of project (directory where `package.json` file is located) i get these error:

```
[cookie@c-linux-43 hra]$ npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/cookie/.npm/_logs/2022-08-06T09_08_27_503Z-debug-0.log
[cookie@c-linux-43 hra]$
```

But `start` is actually defined in `package.json` (line 8)!

```json
{
  "name": "cookieho-hra",
  "productName": "cookieho-hra",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Electron application description",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "eslint src --color"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "cookie",
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "make_targets": {
        "win32": [
          "squirrel"
        ],
        "darwin": [
          "zip"
        ],
        "linux": [
          "deb",
          "rpm"
        ]
      },
      "electronPackagerConfig": {
        "packageManager": "npm"
      },
      "electronWinstallerConfig": {
        "name": "cookieho_hra"
      },
      "electronInstallerDebian": {},
      "electronInstallerRedhat": {},
      "github_repository": {
        "owner": "",
        "name": ""
      },
      "windowsStoreConfig": {
        "packageName": "",
        "name": "cookiehohra"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-compile": "^6.4.4",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.4",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1"
  }
}
```

This is a log (`/home/cookie/.npm/_logs/2022-08-06T09_08_27_503Z-debug-0.log`):

```
[cookie@c-linux-43 ~]$ cat /home/cookie/.npm/_logs/2022-08-06T09_08_27_503Z-debug-0.log
0 verbose cli /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/npm
1 info using npm@8.16.0
2 info using node@v18.7.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 5ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 4ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 6ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:/home/cookie/Plocha/projekty/hra/.npmrc Completed in 3ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 78ms
11 timing config:load:file:/home/cookie/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 2ms
13 timing config:load:file:/usr/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 2ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 20ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 3ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 124ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 125ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 3ms
21 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 2ms
22 verbose title npm start
23 verbose argv "start"
24 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 4ms
25 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 9ms
26 timing npm:load:display Completed in 16ms
27 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/home/cookie/.npm/_logs
28 verbose logfile /home/cookie/.npm/_logs/2022-08-06T09_08_27_503Z-debug-0.log
29 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 18ms
30 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 1ms
31 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
32 timing npm:load Completed in 171ms
33 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
34 silly logfile done cleaning log files
35 timing command:run-script Completed in 45ms
36 timing command:start Completed in 62ms
37 verbose stack Error: Missing script: "start"
37 verbose stack
37 verbose stack Did you mean one of these?
37 verbose stack     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
37 verbose stack     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
37 verbose stack
37 verbose stack To see a list of scripts, run:
37 verbose stack   npm run
37 verbose stack     at RunScript.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/run-script.js:98:13)
37 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:78:5)
38 verbose cwd /home/cookie/Plocha/projekty/hra
39 verbose Linux 5.18.9-arch1-1
40 verbose node v18.7.0
41 verbose npm  v8.16.0
42 error Missing script: "start"
42 error
42 error Did you mean one of these?
42 error     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
42 error     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
42 error
42 error To see a list of scripts, run:
42 error   npm run
43 verbose exit 1
44 timing npm Completed in 281ms
45 verbose code 1
46 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
46 error     /home/cookie/.npm/_logs/2022-08-06T09_08_27_503Z-debug-0.log
[cookie@c-linux-43 ~]$
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What does `npm run` say?

Comment: Forgive me the dumb questions but 1) are you sure you are executing that command in the correct directory and 2) are you sure you have saved the `package.json` file?